# I've got a vector map file that I need to cut in half

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tiles

The idea is to have a perfect cut with points on any line crossing the "cut line". Keeping both top and bottom files correct. These are complex lines that have to come back together. The end result is to laser cut the files larger to recreate the map in tiles. I've been doing it with the erase tool (alt for getting a rectangle erase). There are so many layers I have to repeat this on I'm just trying to figure out best practice here.

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry - Illustrator 2019

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do NOT need to maintain the current layer structure for these "pieces"....

## notes....

- Copy the file so you are working on a duplicate 
  ("coming back together" is a task unto itself, this solves that)
- Pathfinder functions will **not** cut raster images, linked or embedded.
- If you have things such as raster effect, i.e. glows, drop shadows, etc, they may be altered by the Pathfinder operation.
- Pathfinder functions may not cut stroked, open, paths. Or may simply *remove* strokes form objects. You *may* need to expand artwork first

---

## Working on the copied file....

- Place everything on one layer (easiest way is to Select All and `Object > Group`)

---

I don't know if it's feasible, but merely using 2 layers with a clipping mask on each layer to hide half should work just as well and save the trouble of actually "cutting" anything.

---

or...

- You can **expand** the artwork
- Duplicate the layer so you have two copies
- Draw a rectangle on one layer covering the left side
- Select all on this layer and Pathfinder > Crop
- Repeat for other side.

---

or...

- Draw a line where you want the cut
- Ensure the line is on top of everything
- Select all
- Pathfinder Panel > Divide
- Duplicate the layer and turn off the duplicate's layer visibility
- Select left side and <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Turn off visibility of this layer and move to duplicated layer (turn on it's visibility)
- Select right side and <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- Turn on visibility for left side layer

That *should* give you two halves, each on it's own layer.

---

Without more detailed information regarding the exact nature of the artwork, these basic steps *should* work.

---

Comment: Thanks Scott for your insight. There are no rasters, just vector lines. If you look at my work on dsmaps.com it will help to see the maps. The only way I've found to "cut" these for tiling was to put a line on each side of the cut and make sure every line that crosses gets a point. Very time consuming. The divide in pathfinder doesn't work because it causes havock across the rest of the maps labeling, etc. Because these have to be so simplified for the laser it's a much different approach in the design.

Comment: Scott - thank you! It was a combination of steps that did work. I've taught most of the Adobe product line over the years and am still involved with beta testing. What is incredulous is the lack of snap tools in illustrator that can be assigned and saved. grid works but not quite enough options. Snap to guides that could go from one project to the next would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out all of the options suggested created new geometry that is not holding the stroke to it's original line weight and it created an outline around all the geometry in the map layer. Unfortunately, this is still not answered. I'm happy to upload a file to play with so you can see what happens when making these transformations.